# How to count how many clients are in a django channels Group

Tags: django, websocket, channel, django-channels

I would like to know how to count the number of clients in a Django Channels Group in order to restrict the number of connected clients for example.

I tried to look in the code of Group object but I had no success.

Here my code:

```
import re
import json
from channels import Group
from channels.sessions import channel_session
from login import login


@channel_session
def ws_connect(message):

    print "Connected"


    if Group("guis").count() > 10: # NOT POSSIBLE

        Group("guis").add(message.reply_channel)
        message.reply_channel.send({'accept': True})

    else:
        message.reply_channel.send({'accept': True})
```

Answer (score 2):

I dug around the source code a little bit and found the `group_channels` method. Try:

```
len(Group('guis').channel_layer.group_channels('guis'))
```

I don't know if this is the right way to do it or if it will work for all backends but at least it is a starting point.